# Spring boot: Set logging level for specific method in specific class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

We can set logging level for specific class or package in Spring boot in properties file like this:

```
logging.level.com.alibaba.druid=info
```

but is it possible for us to set logging level for specific method?

I searched around but couldn't find much useful information.

I would expect a configuration work like this:

```
logging.level.com.alibaba.druid.className#methodName=info
```

Comment: Not unless you have a specific logger for that. It is not so much you set logging for a class orp ackage that is a result of the class/package being part of the logger category. The category can be anything.

Comment: May be you can design your own appender implementation, and config it in your logback.xml.